# Best way handle Features that has boolean value?

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I am currently working on a dataset containing feature vector words.The feature vector consists of ordinal as well as binary data type, majority of them are binary data. for eg ( F,T,F,T,T,36).
How do I represent such data effectively so that machine learning algorithms outputs the probability value of the predicted class?

Comment: This depends of what machine learning algorithm you would be applying. Some algorithms will be better aligned to work on binary features such as naive bayes classifiers or Markov models whereas k-means clustering is not.

Comment: Binary data is "nominal", try searching for "encoding nominal feature" on Google and on this site. There are tens (if not more) of threads on this website (on the question) you are asking.